# Ошибка линковщика при компиляции кода с ключевым словом extern

Tags: c++

Тренируюсь использовать `extern`. Есть два файла с кодом.

global.cpp:

```
const int g_m{10};
const int g_n{3};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
extern const int g_m;
extern const int g_n;
int main(void)
{
    
    std::cout << g_m << "\n" << g_n << "\n";
}
```

Получаю ошибку линковщика:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccOgPFO7.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `g_m'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `g_n'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Без `const` всё работает хорошо.

Также вопрос: можно ли использовать `extern` совместно с `const`? (ответьте с простым примером).

Comment: Не уверен, как именно по стандарту, но теряется сам смысл - инициализированная во время компиляции константа может быть подставлена непосредственно, например, для создания массива. С `extern` так не получится.

Comment: @Mikhailo получается использовать `extern` с константами не имеет смысла?

Comment: Я не знаю правильный ответ, поэтому и пишу в комментариях только свои мысли :) Что касается `const int`, то да, я считаю так.

Comment: @Mikhailo Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос: _По умолчанию, глобальные константные переменные имеют внутреннюю связь. Вы можете использовать ключевое слово extern, чтобы сделать их внешними._ Но не понятно одно, действительно ли в реальной практике `const` будет полезно совместно с `extern` :)

Comment: extern переменные не нужны в принципе. Делайте геттеры и сеттеры.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При компиляции с константными переменными компилятор делает их статическими. И видимости из других исходников нет. Правильное решение это добавить `extern` в этих константах.

global.cpp:

```
extern const int g_m{10};
extern const int g_n{3};
```

---

Или можно *предварительно* объявить эти переменные в хедере обязательно с обозначением `extern`.

global.hpp

```
extern int const g_m ;
extern int const g_n ;
```

И в обоих `.cpp` файлах его нужно подключать.

---

Стандарт говорит про это так :

> ### 6.6 Program and linkage

> A name having namespace scope (6.4.6) has **internal** linkage if it is the name of

> — a variable, variable template, function, or function template that is explicitly declared **static**; **or**

> — a non-template variable of non-volatile **const**-qualified type, unless

> — it is explicitly declared extern, or

> — it is inline or exported, or

> — it was previously declared and the prior declaration did not have internal linkage; or

> — a data member of an anonymous union.

> [Note 1 : An instantiated variable template that has const-qualified type can have external or module linkage, even if
> not declared extern. — end note]

Аналогичный вопрос по английски обсуждался здесь :

[Why does "extern const int n;" not work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894897)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и полезную ссылку, буду ознакамливаться!