# Создание глобальной структуры

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли создать глобально структуру, так, чтобы не нужно было в других файлах полностью прописывать внутренности структуры ?

Ну то есть, вот есть у меня к примеру пять .cpp файлов, условно в первом я объявляю структуру, в остальных четырех делаю extern и прописываю полностью внутренности структуры.
Если вдруг внутренности структуры меняются, добавляется или удаляется какое то поле к примеру, то во всех остальных четырех файлах, нужно проделывать туже операцию, что, как бы не очень удобно.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>  


struct my_struct
{
    int my_int;
    std::string my_string;
};

my_struct mystrct;

void my_func()
{
    mystrct.my_int = 555;
}
```

h

```
#include <iostream>           
#include <string> 


extern struct my_struct
{
    int my_int;
    std::string my_string;
};

extern my_struct mystrct;

int main()
{
    my_func();

    std::cout << mystrct.my_int;

}
```

Вот можно ли, как то избежать прописывание тела структуры в остальных файлах кроме первоначального, где объявлялась структура ?

Comment: Перенести в заголовочный файл и включать его в .cpp-файлы...

Comment: Странно, вопрос про структуру, а потом внезапно extern вылезает. Привели бы лучше пример.

Comment: @user7860670, отредактировал и добавил код. Но так и не понял, почему у Вас вызвал вопрос extern ?

Comment: Потому что вопрос был про внутренности структуры, однако extern не используется при объявлении структуры. Ну а вообще см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1332256/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-extern#comment2356386_1332256